# Python: enclose each word of a space separated string in quotes

Tags: python, string

I have a string eg:

```py
line = "a sentence with a few words"
```

I want to convert the above in a string with each of the words in double quotes, eg:

```py
'"a" "sentence" "with" "a" "few" "words"'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to split the string? Try `words = line.split()`

Comment: @vaultah I need the result in the form of the string with quotes. Your suggestion results in a list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Split the line into words, wrap each word in quotes, then re-join:

```
' '.join('"{}"'.format(word) for word in line.split(' '))
```

Comment: That was pretty quick! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Since you say:

> I want to convert the above in a string with each of the words in double quotes

You can use the following regex:

```
>>> line="a sentence with a few words"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)',r'"\1"',line)
'"a" "sentence" "with" "a" "few" "words"'
```

This would take into consideration punctuations, etc, as well (if that is really what you wanted):

```
>>> line="a sentence with a few words. And, lots of punctuations!"
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)',r'"\1"',line)
'"a" "sentence" "with" "a" "few" "words". "And", "lots" "of" "punctuations"!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can something simpler (more implementation but easier for beginners) by searching for each space in the quote then slice whatever between the spaces, add " before and after it then print it.

```
quote = "they stumble who run fast"
first_space = 0
last_space = quote.find(" ")
while last_space != -1:
    print("\"" + quote[first_space:last_space] + "\"")
    first_space = last_space + 1
    last_space = quote.find(" ",last_space + 1)
```

Above code will output for you the following:

```
"they"
"stumble"
"who"
"run"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer missed an instance of the original quote. The last string/word "fast" was not printed.
This solution will print the last string:

```
quote = "they stumble who run fast"

start = 0
location = quote.find(" ")

while location >=0:
    index_word = quote[start:location]
    print(index_word)

    start = location + 1
    location = quote.find(" ", location + 1)

#this runs outside the While Loop, will print the final word
index_word = quote[start:]
print(index_word)
```

**This is the result:**

```
they
stumble
who
run
fast
```

Comment: thanks @StephenRauch, I removed the redundant if statement

Comment: You now have a `::`